# Find the expected value of tickets that the player should buy, in order to get a super prize.

Tags: probability, expected-value, coupon-collector

> In a lottery, there are $K$ distinct prizes. The probability of winning any one of the prizes is the same for every ticket and is equal to $1/K$. In case the player wins all $K$ prizes, he will get a super prize. Find the expected value of tickets that the player should buy, in order to get a super prize.

My attempt: Let $X$ be the random variable that denotes the number of tickets bought. And I thought it is a binomial distribution, where $X\ge K$ and $P(X=k) = {n \choose k}p^kq^{n-k}$, $k=K$ is number of successes out of $n$ trials. But I am stuck.

Actually, I don't know how to do it right. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The rules aren't clear.  Are you guaranteed to win a prize with each ticket?  Might you win more than one prize with a single ticket?

Comment: @lulu for each ticket you may win at most 1 prize

Comment: This sounds alot similar to coupon collector's problem.

Comment: So...the probability of winning no prize at all is $\left( \frac {K-1}K\right)^K$?  Thus, if $K$ is large, it is effectively $\frac 1e$?  If so, then it is the same as the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), where you have a significant probability of getting no coupon at all.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define the random variable $X$ which counts the number of trials needed to win $K$ prices.

Let's notice that $X \in \{K,K+1,\cdots \}$.

$\mathbb{P}(X=n)$ is simply the binomial distribution, which we know equals to

$$\mathbb{P}(X=n) = \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{n-k}$$

What we are looking for in order to solve the problem is by defition $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum\limits n\cdot p_{X}(n)$

Where $p_{X}(n)= \mathbb{P}(X=n)$

Otherwise said : 
$$ \mathbb{E}[X]  = \sum\limits_{n=K}^{\infty} n \binom{n}{K}\left(\frac{1}{K}\right)^{K}\left(1-\frac{1}{K}\right)^{n-K}$$

Which unfortunately I was unable to evaluate, but according to [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bn%3Dk%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+n+binom%28n%2Ck%29%281%2Fk%29%5E%28k%29%281-1%2Fk%29%5E%28n-k%29) $$\sum\limits_{n=K}^{\infty} n \binom{n}{K}\left(\frac{1}{K}\right)^{K}\left(1-\frac{1}{K}\right)^{n-K} = K^{3}+K^{2}-K$$

Because $K^{3}+K^{2}-K \geq 0$ $\forall \hspace{0.1cm} K \in \mathbb{N}$ it seems a reasonable result due to the fact that the number of prizes is a positive integer.